# Better quality for camera preview frame

Tags: android, android-camera, zxing

I write an application for Motorola Xoom tablet with Android 3.1 for my master thesis that can scan multiple QR Codes in real time with it's camera and that displays additional information in the display over recognised QR Codes.

The recognition is done with the ZXing android app (http://code.google.com/p/zxing/), I basically just changed the code of the ZXing app so that it can recognise multiple QR Codes at the same time and can do this scan continually, without freezing after a successful scan like the original app does. So my app is basically the ZXing app with continous scanning of multiple QR Codes.

But I'm facing a problem:

1. The recognition rate of QR Codes with the built in camera is not
   very good. The ZXing app uses the pictures that it gets from the
   camera preview. But these pictures do not have a very good quality.
   Is there any possibility to make the camera preview making better
   quality pictures?

   P.S. I also tried to make real snapshots with camera.takePicture()
   to get a better quality, but it takes too long to take the picture
   so the real time experience for the user is lost.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the question would be... why is the image quality that bad? Do the image have low resolution? Is the preview out of focus? I've worked with the ZXing Android app before and I know that it has a mechanism to keep the camera auto focusing the live scene.

If the auto focus mechanism is undergoing, then you are possibly decoding some images that might be out of focus. Rationaly, it would make sense to decode only when the camera is in focus, but that would delay the decoding process, since it would have to wait for the focusing to do the image processing phase.  However, I wouldn't be too much worried about this for several reasons: 1) the auto focus is very quick, so there will be very few blurry images (if there are any at all), 2) the camera keeps focus for a sufficient amount of time that would allow for a couple decodings, 3) QRCodes typically do not require perfect images to be detected and decoded - they were designed that way.

If this is a problem for you, then disable the continous auto-focus and set the parameter to anything that suits you.

If the problem comes from low resolution frames, well increase it..., but QRCodes were also designed to be identified even in small resolutions. Also, keep in mind the increasing the resolution will also increase decoding time...

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts. I know that QR Codes are designed to be recognised only on bad images. But my app idealy should work also from bigger distances such as 1 meter for example. So the QR Code is already quite small. If the image is not perfectly in focus, recognition has no chance.